# How do I add this Technician Course I took in highschool in my canadian resume?

Tags: resume

I have a technician degree in Informatics (image bellow is the certificate) and I would like to hear your opinion on how to add this in a resume. 
I've tried "Information Technology Technician by the Federal Institute of Technology, Science and Education of Minas Gerais", does it make any sense? The course is a 3 years course with interniship required.
[image: declaration]

Comment: Looks fine to me

Answer (score 1):

We're no different than the prospective employer, and you explained what this is to us by saying:

```
The course is a 3 years course with interniship required.
```

Something like:

```
Information Technology Technician certification, Federal Institute of Technology, Science and Education of Mina Gerais

 - Three year program with internship at ____.
```

Then I would list the internship as a separate item under experience, like any normal job, with the job title "intern".

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like education. I would put it under the education category as just a short certification. In an interview you would likely be given the opportunity to explain it further.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with **Information Technology Technician, certified through the Federal Institute of Technology, Science and Education of Minas Gerais** as a line in the education section.